# Adding days to a DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, integer

Is it possible to add dates  in C#?

```
(DateTime.Today.ToLongDateString() + 10)
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you want to add days?

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
```

Note that you get a new DateTime back!

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

Use `DateTime.Today.AddDays(10)` or any of the other AddXXX functions on DateTime.

Answer (score 6):

What is the unit of 10.  If it is days; then

```
var todayPlus10Days = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use AddDays() method:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
dt = dt.AddDays(10);
```