# multiply year to date in c#?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

This is my continuation of my work: [Adding DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106671/adding-datetime-in-c)
I already can add days on my date.

My Question is:

a.) it is possible to multiply a year to datetime?
 eg.

```
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10);
long xDate = DateTime.Now.Year * newDate; // error : Operator '*' 
           // cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.DateTime
```

Comment: What is this for? I don't understand what you're trying to do, sorry...

Comment: What would you expect the result to mean?

Comment: You can argue, multiplying is only repeated addition, eg 4x4 = 4+4+4+4 ....

Comment: im just trying to multiply a year to datetime.. i need this for authentication

Comment: Yeah but if you don't know what the result should be than how should we now it?

Comment: Please tell us what that result should be. It just makes no sense. This is what you are asking: 2011 * 2011-05-31

Comment: @Margarrete: nice authentication :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
 DateTime newDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(10); 
            long xDate = DateTime.Now.Year * newDate.Year;
```

Comment: just wait 8mins and i'll accept your answer.. tnx!

Comment: Why your comment contains a question mark :)

Comment: @Margarrete: You need to learn to be more precise in your questions.

Comment: @Margarrete: Your question is: `it is possible to multiply a year to datetime?`. This answer is not for that question. However, I hope that is what you realy need.

Comment: The `AddDays` part is useless unless the current date is less than 10 days from new year.

Comment: I am sorry but Year * Year is just multiplying an int * int it has nothing to do with the original question.Moreover what is the point of multiplying years anyway?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this, but i don't really understand why multiplying, you will get very big number for a year. Here is the idea:

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year * newDate.Year;
DateTime xDate = new DateTime(year, newDate.Month, newDate.Day);
```

Comment: The "year" part of a DateTime  can't be more than 9999, so this will throw an error.

Comment: I thought so too, but that is his requirement. I really don't understand why he want's it.